# Как использовать оператор = при перегрузке

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

я новичок в изучении ООП С++ и дошел до темы "перегрузка операторов". Подскажите, как использовать оператор "=" для присвоения элементу массива значение после перегрузки такого вида?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {

private:
    int *array = new int[10];

public:
    base();
    base(int n);
    int operator=(int value);
};

base::base() {

}

int base::operator=(int value) {
    array[0] = value;
    return array[0];
}
base::base(int i) {

}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить? Например, есть `base b;` - что вы хотите получить при `b = 5;`?

Comment: Я хотел бы просто присвоить значение что введет пользователь с помощью перегрузки в массив. Или это не так работает?

Comment: Обычно оператор = используется для присвоения нового значения всем объекту. То бишь для изменения / перевыделения array в данном случае.

Comment: Просто у меня не вышло разобраться с тем как присвоить значение в array[0]. Пытался найти в интернете, но натыкался только на примеры где используется тип класса,а массив у меня целочисленный. Выходит что я не смогу таким образом присвоить значение в массив с помощью перегрузки?

Comment: *не вышло разобраться с тем как присвоить значение в array[0].* - что значит "не вышло"? В приведенном коде оно присваивается, хотя бы и кривовато. Если хочется присвоить, то сделали бы простую функцию `set_item(::std::size_t const index, int const new_value)`

Comment: Я имел ввиду что не вышло додуматься как это использовать в main, в связи с тем что оператор "=" новинка для меня. Извините за неправильную формулировку